# Why won't cursor changes in Windows stay permanent unless the cursors are in Windows/Cursors

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, cursor

Every time I change my cursor in Windows, when I restart my PC it reverts back to the aero cursors. Looking on the internet for a while, a number of websites say that cursors have to be in C:\Windows\Cursors. Why does this happen? When it reverts to aero, I go to the mouse options, and all my settings are there but I have to click "OK" to set it to my custom settings again.

Comment: Odd, doesn't happen here.

Comment: The cursors have to be in C:/Windows/Cursors , did you try it outside of that folder?